# What are practical uses for the Triangle Matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, data-analysis

So I'm learning data science concepts for analysis of stock price data and I've gone into a rabbit hole.  I first came across `numpy.triu()` in the Numpy library which calculates the Triangle Matrix for a dataset to find large movements in stock price points over a range of time.

Then I learned more about the concept and how values in the set are calculated.

But now I'm wondering what the practical uses for this concept?   I'm especially interested in uses in analyzing stock price data.

Comment: Solving $Ax=b$ with the LU decomposition.